# Fast Update database with more than 10 million records

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, toad

I am fairly new to SQL and was wondering if someone can help me.

I got a database that has around 10 million rows.

I need to make a script that finds the records that have some NULL fields, and then updates it to a certain value.

The problem I have from doing a simple update statement, is that it will blow the rollback space.

I was reading around that I need to use BULK COLLECT AND FETCH.

My idea was to fetch 10,000 records at a time, update, commit, and continue fetching.

I tried looking for examples on Google but I have not found anything yet.

Any help?

Thanks!!

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR rec_cur IS
    SELECT DATE_ORIGIN 
    FROM MAIN_TBL WHERE DATE_ORIGIN IS NULL;

    TYPE date_tab_t IS TABLE OF DATE;

    date_tab date_tab_t;

BEGIN
    OPEN rec_cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH rec_cur BULK COLLECT INTO date_tab LIMIT 1000;
        EXIT WHEN date_tab.COUNT() = 0;

        FORALL i IN 1 .. date_tab.COUNT
            UPDATE MAIN_TBL SET DATE_ORIGIN  = '23-JAN-2012' 
            WHERE DATE_ORIGIN IS NULL;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE rec_cur;
END;
```

Comment: So, you've tried the single `UPDATE` statement and it generated an error?  What was the exact error?  If the error was that you were out of `UNDO` space, have you asked the DBA to increase the `UNDO` space?  10 million rows isn't a lot-- your database really ought to be sized to handle the reasonable workload you want to put on it rather than trying to write code to save a few MB of disk space.

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  Post some code and someone might be able to critique it for you.

Comment: the database is a production server, so we haven't done the single update statement yet, but from my bosses experience, it has crashed before...can it still be possible to do it in bulk fetch style ?

Comment: I added at the bottom what I have so far I get the following Error: PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannnot be used inside FORALL

Comment: Your current code doesn't really make sense. Firstly, your `rec_cur` cursor is defined to return only `NULL`s: it gives you no information about the records you want to update. Secondly, your `UPDATE` doesn't have anything in its `WHERE`-clause to restrict it to the record you want to update; it's just doing the full, original update that includes all records. Thirdly, I don't *think* that this approach will decrease the amount of `UNDO`-space you need, because your transaction will still be just as big as it was.

Comment: (By the way, the error-message is referring to my "secondly" point: inside the `FORALL`, Oracle requires that the `UPDATE` statement refer in some way to some field of `date_tab(i)`. But before you can fix that, you need to address my "firstly" point.)

Comment: @ruakh, the amount of undo space needed could be decreased by a commit after every `forall` loop but your other points do mean it's all pointless.

Comment: @Ben: Right, but only because adding a `COMMIT` means it's no longer a single transaction!

Comment: What version of oracle are you running?

Comment: Do you absolutely _need_ this to be in a transaction?  I mean, is some sort of referential integrity dependant on this?  If you only have reporting processes that look at this field, why not suspend them until the entire update is done?  Then you could theorhetically run this as `WITH NC` (no commitment control)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do. There are a number of points I want to make about the differences between the code below and yours.

1. Your `forall` loop **will not** use an index. This is easy to get round by using `rowid` to update your table.
2. By committing after each `forall` you reduce the amount of undo needed; but make it more difficult to rollback if something goes wrong. Though logically your query could be re-started in the middle easily and without detriment to your objective.
3. `rowids` are small, collect at least 25k at a time; if not 100k.
4. You cannot index a null in Oracle. There are plenty of questions on stackoverflow about this is you need more information. A functional index on something like `nvl(date_origin,'x')` as a loose example would increase the speed at which you select data. It also means you never actually have to use the table itself. You only select from the index.
5. Your date data-type seems to be a string. I've kept this but it's not wise.
6. If you can get someone to increase your undo tablespace size then a straight up update will be quicker.

Assuming as per your comments `date_origin` is a date then the index should be on something like:

```
nvl(date_origin,to_date('absolute_minimum_date_in_Oracle_as_a_string','yyyymmdd'))
```

I don't have access to a DB at the moment but to find out the `amdiOaas` run the following query:

```
select to_date('0001','yyyy') from dual;
```

It should raise a useful error for you.

---

Working example in PL/SQL Developer.

```
 create table main_tbl as
  select cast( null as date ) as date_origin
    from all_objects
         ;

create index i_main_tbl
   on main_tbl ( nvl( to_date(date_origin,'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    , to_date('0001-01-01' ,'yyyy-mm-dd') )
                )
      ;

declare

   cursor c_rec is
    select rowid
      from main_tbl
     where nvl(date_origin,to_date('0001-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) 
               = to_date('0001-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
          ;

   type t__rec is table of rowid index by binary_integer;
   t_rec t__rec;

begin

   open c_rec;
   loop

      fetch c_rec bulk collect into t_rec limit 50000;

      exit when t_rec.count = 0;

      forall i in t_rec.first .. t_rec.last
         update main_tbl
            set date_origin = to_date('23-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
          where rowid = t_rec(i)
                ;
         commit ;

   end loop;
   close c_rec;
end;
/
```

Comment: thanks Ben! this seems like a great approach, for some reason the code is bombing in forall i in t_rec.first .. t_rec.last loop PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following

Comment: @xela_austin that's because I've made my most common Oracle mistake. `forall` doesn't require `loop`; I've updated my answer. See [here](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html) for a more documentation.

Comment: thanks again! now it says ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.. this happens in fetch c_rec bulk collect into t_rec limit 50000;

Comment: @xela_austin, there is no mistake in my code round there. Check out the documentation. I can only guess that you've written `50,000` or not created the type as a rowid type etc... or your date is actually a number not a date or a character.

Comment: I checked the 3 cases but still no luck.. I am using 50000 (not 50,000), the type it is rowid...and using TOAD I made a describe on the table and the dat_origin colum it is of type of DATE.... :/

Comment: I changed the where nvl(date_origin,'x') = 'x'; to where date_origin is null; and that does run...however my main_tbl doesnt show the new changes

Comment: @xela_austin, as I said if you want this to go quickly you have to index that combination. I did it assuming your `date_origin` was a string as that was what your question said. I'll change it to a date-example now. However, if `select * from main_tbl where date_origin is null` returns nothing then you have achieved your goal, no?

Comment: basically...if a row in date_origin is NULL, I want to be updated to '23-JAN-2012'...btw, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I ran the code again I set where nvl(date_origin ,to_date('00010201','yyyymmdd'))= to_date('00010201','yyyymmdd')

and also changed update main_tab to main_tbl...the code runs, but after it finishes and I do select * from main_tbl...date_origin did not get updated to 23-JAN-2012...do you think it has something to do with the where clause where rowid = t_rec(i)  ??? thanks!

Comment: @xela_austin, did you commit ?

Comment: @xela_austin, I've updated my answer with a working example in PL/SQL developer...